# How to translate「今日は別行動」?

Tags: translation

As far as I know, 別行動する means something along the lines of 'to do something separately (from a group)' but I think here 別行動 is a noun, with だ omitted. I'd like to know the closest possible translation without turning nouns into verbs or anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Japanese conversation uses a LOT of shortcuts. While the language is notable for having consistent rules and not breaking them... much... (unlike English), Japanese in "everyday" speech patterns is very relaxed, which often means omitting particles of speech like "o" "ga", and sentence final "da/desu", as well as verb endings that can be understood from context like "suru"

l'electeur is correct, "As for today, separate ways." is one way to literally translate that phrase, as is "Today, we'll be separate." (as you noted the only concepts/words actually there are "today" and "separate actions")

A more flowing translation would be "Today let's each do our own thing."

and you are again correct in thinking that a more grammatically proper way of saying this would be 今日は別行動をする。　（しましょう）

by the way, 別行動 is a noun, of course, whether you add する or だ doesn't change that... it's just that in Japanese, "verbing" a noun is not strange.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted a super-literal translation even if it did not sound natural in the target language (English),

> "As for today, separate ways."

would be one such example.